# How to deal with complex internal jar dependency management

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jar, dependencies

Our shop has traditionally been about on single large j2ee application.  However, we are moving towards numerous more narrowly focused applications.  Each app has certain amount of shared code it needs to rely on that we are keeping in various jar files.

The problem is that as development changes one jar because of the needs of one application, we may not always be ready to deploy app 2 that relies on the same jar.  Thus we end up versioning the jars.  And as release schedules become convoluted (and life has a way of making thing convoluted) we find we are constantly being challenged to manage this.

I feel like we must be doing it wrong.  Life shouldn't be this complicated.  Does Maven make this sort of thing easy?  We've shied away from Maven because our work environment is one where a tool going out to the internet to download software is going to be frowned upon, but if it simplifies this problem of building and managing dependencies within the project...well, maybe.

Anyway, advice anyone?

Answer (score 1):

If you like everything about Maven except talking to the internet, you should use Maven. All you need to do is install a local repository manager (Nexus, Artifactory, etc) to get control on the process of pulling in open source from the internet, and then the rest is up to you.

Also note that if you are already an 'ant' shop, you can get some dependency relief from ivy. If, however, the Maven automation for making releases appeals to you, then ivy isn't any help.

*However*, Maven is just a tool for managing dependencies and versions. It is not a magic bullet. If upgrading 'thing B' to deal with changes to 'thing A' is a hard job, maybe what you really need to do is rethink your attitude towards modularity and APIs and compatibility. If you think about your components as if you were a vendor selling a library to customers who expect smooth transitions, then making your apps eat new versions of your components might get less painful.

I strongly recommend that you do some sort of experiment or prototype and get some experience with the tool before trying to use it in production, let alone before trying to convince someone else to do so.

Comment: It's not so much that I LIKE everything about maven except that, so much as I don't KNOW anything about Maven except that.  If it were my decision alone, we'd use Maven, but I need to sell the idea to uppers, and if it were to make that aspect easier, that would make it an easy sell.